# Progress bar of multi step form is hidding behind the white background color of container DIV

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some simple HTML, CSS and jQuery. Everything works well except that the progress bar lines(Connector between the number and names below each number) is hiding behind the white container class background.

I tried to removed white background from container class and then everything works well. I tried changing the Z-index, but that did not work.

This is called in Master Page  _Layout File in MVC

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:white;"></div>
```

So I create Test.cshtml Page and have this code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="background-color:none;">
            <!-- multistep form -->
            <form id="msform" style="margin-top:150px; height:500px;">
                <!-- progressbar -->
                <ul id="progressbar">
                    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
                    <li>Social Profiles</li>
                    <li>Personal Details</li>
                </ul>
                <!-- fieldsets -->
                <fieldset>
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
                    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
                    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
                    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /*custom font*/
  /*  @@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);*/

    /*form styles*/
    #msform {
        width: 400px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

        #msform fieldset {
            background: white;
            border: 0 none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            padding: 20px 30px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 10%;
            /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
            position: absolute;
        }
            /*Hide all except first fieldset*/
            #msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
                display: none;
            }
        /*inputs*/
        #msform input, #msform textarea {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: montserrat;
            color: #2C3E50;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        /*buttons*/
        #msform .action-button {
            width: 100px;
            background: #27AE60;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            border: 0 none;
            border-radius: 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            margin: 10px 5px;
        }

            #msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
            }
    /*headings*/
    .fs-title {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #2C3E50;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .fs-subtitle {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #666;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    /*progressbar*/
    #progressbar {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
        counter-reset: step;
    }

        #progressbar li {
            list-style-type: none;
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 9px;
            width: 33.33%;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }

            #progressbar li:before {
                content: counter(step);
                counter-increment: step;
                width: 20px;
                line-height: 20px;
                display: block;
                font-size: 10px;
                color: #333;
                background: white;
                border-radius: 3px;
                margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
            }
            /*progressbar connectors*/
            #progressbar li:after {
                content: '';
                width: 100%;
                height: 2px;
                background: black;
                position: absolute;
                left: -50%;
                top: 9px;
                z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
            }

            #progressbar li:first-child:after {
                /*connector not needed before the first step*/
                content: none;
            }
            /*marking active/completed steps green*/
            /*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
            #progressbar li.active:before, #progressbar li.active:after {
                background: #27AE60;
                color: white;
            }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery time
    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

    $(".next").click(function () {
        if (animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

        //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        //show the next fieldset
        next_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
            step: function (now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50) + "%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')' });
                next_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function () {
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

    $(".previous").click(function () {
        if (animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
            step: function (now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({ 'left': left });
                previous_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')', 'opacity': opacity });
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function () {
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

    $(".submit").click(function () {
        return false;
    })

</script>
```

Here's the image below how it looks when I remove white background of container. This is how I want to see even if container has white background.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of your your outer `div` elements here, you are using `background-color:none`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="background-color:none;">
```

At present, this means the unwanted white background from the containing `div` is what the progress bar line shows.

So instead of setting of `none`in that `div`, set the desired background colour of the progress bar line.

Comment: Yes this works great @Reg Edit & and i have added z-index:1 to the form `<form id="msform" style="margin-top: 150px; height: 500px;z-index: 1;">`